# How do I compute the accuracy in groups?

Tags: accuracy

A paper [Assessment of Deep Generative Models for High-Resolution Synthetic Retinal Image Generation of Age-Related Macular Degeneration](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6439721/) performed an experiment and the result is

> Retinal specialists could not distinguish real from synthetic images, with an **accuracy of
>   59.50%** (error margin, 3.93%) for retinal specialist 1 and **53.67%**(error margin, 3.99%) for
>   retinal specialist 2.

I partly understand what the researchers did, they invited 2 retinal specialists do something like the following respectively,

They gave specialist 1 a set of images, told they that set consists of real images and synthetic images (simply, some kind of fake images), asked they pick **real images** from the set, and stat how many "real images" in the ones (let's call it #specialist_1_picked) specialist 1 picked are actually "real images" (let's call it #actually_real_in_1)

They asked specialist 2 do the experiment separately and stated the same metrics.

[image]

The question is what is the exact formula to compute those accuracies **59.50%** and **53.67%**. Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accuracy (as well as the other abbreviations in your table) is defined on [the Wikipedia page on sensitivity and specificity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity). Specifically, accuracy is defined as

$$ \text{ACC}:=\frac{\text{TP}+\text{TN}}{\text{P}+\text{N}}. $$

[Accuracy is not a good measure for assessing classification models.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352)

Comment: Thank you. Is the #actually_real_in_1 in my OP the TP in your formula?

Comment: Yes, that's it.